# JPA/Hibernate DDL generation; CHAR vs. VARCHAR

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-annotations

I have a JPA/Hibernate data model that I am using the Hibernate hbm2ddl tool to generate database DDL. I have some strings that should be CHAR and some that may be VARCHAR in the database. I want to minimize hand editing of the DDL (I realize that some will have to happen).

Anyone know how I should go about this? I realize that I can make all Strings VARCHARS or CHARS via a hacked dialect, but that isn't what is always appropriate in the database.

I would like to be able to do this with annotations or aop, avoiding custom column definition text in my classes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, I finally found that you can specify a length limit for a type in the dialect. So, I've decided that anything under a length of 10 should be char and anything over that should be varchar:

```
registerColumnType( Types.VARCHAR, 10, "char($l)" );
```

That isn't exactly what I was wanting, but that is good enough. Sad that I didn't find that earlier.

Answer (score 16):

Annotate the strings you want to map to a CHAR in the database with
`@Column(columnDefinition="CHAR(<your-char-length>)")`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but in my last paragraph, I mention that. I am trying to avoid using columnDefinition. I was just hoping that there was a better way, as this would seem to be a reasonable want.

Comment: There's not much of a difference between adding an annotation vs adding an annotation attribute.

Comment: Ah, but the difference is the contents of the attribute. That is text put directly into the schema ddl, thus, inherently database specific. Also, I have to duplicate the length of the column in the text. This particular instance isn't so bad, but worth avoiding if I can. It isn't looking promising though, I must admit.