# OpenJPA registerColumnType() equivalent

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0, openjpa

With regards to this SO question ( [JPA/Hibernate DDL generation; CHAR vs. VARCHAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290727/jpa-hibernate-ddl-generation-char-vs-varchar) ), I was wondering whether there was any functional equivalent in OpenJPA 2.0.1 to this method found in Hibernate:

```
protected void registerColumnType(int code, String name);
```

I tried to find its approximate correspondence in OpenJPA DBDictionary, but could find none, so if anyone has any idea on how to em-/si-/mulate its behaviour, I'd be much abliged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there are particular reason that you can't use the columnDefinition attribute?

```
@javax.persistence.Basic
@javax.persistence.Column(columnDefinition="CHAR(1)")
private String basic;
```

Comment: Well, no, but if you check out the link in my question, you'll see what I'm getting at - I'd like to set a "cut-off length", which could effectively say "Everything below length X is CHAR(X) type, and anything above is VARCHAR(X) type". It is something Hibernate is supposedly capable of doing (I don't know for sure since I haven't used it).

Comment: Ahhk, makes sense. AFAIK the answer is no, OpenJPA doesn't have that functionality.

Comment: Thx for the comment - I may have found something in the OpenJPA DBDictionary. If I get the time to play with it and make it work, I'll let you know.