# JPA, Hibernate, DB2: JPQL-Query and char column

Tags: hibernate, char, db2, jpql, dialect

I'm using JPA with hibernate and have some trouble with the following JPQL query **:**

```
final Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery(
            "select u from User u where u.username = :username")
query.setParameter("username", "a");
```

When using a DB2 V9.7 database the query leads to a NoResultException even though a user with username 'a' exists. This problem only occurs if the column with the username has the type char. If i change the column type to varchar, like hibernate would generate it by himself, the query works fine.

Any ideas?

Enclosed some configuration information :

- hibernate version: 3.6.10.Final
- jdbc driver: db2jcc 3.61.65
- dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect
- field declaration:

```
     @Column(name = "USER_NAME", length = 50)
     @NotNull
     @Size(max = 50)
     private String username;
```

- user type declaration
  `@TypeDef(name = "trimmedString", defaultForType = String.class, typeClass = TrimmedStringUserType.class)`

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate maps String to VARCHAR type. This is explained here

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/types.html

To make sure it maps to char you need to specify in your custom db2 dialect as mentioned here.

[JPA/Hibernate DDL generation; CHAR vs. VARCHAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290727/jpa-hibernate-ddl-generation-char-vs-varchar)